# Deploying with Build Caching using Docker on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I am attempting to optimize a docker app on Heroku to cache installed dependencies between builds. Thus far, I have been unable to get subsequent builds to use any form of caching. For example, using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
```

If I run `docker build -t test .` locally multiple times I see:

```
docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  92.16kB
Step 1/4 : FROM ruby:2.7.2-alpine
 ---> 79f5adf3c887
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1c42ebe94fa4
Step 3/4 : COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 626c3092389f
Step 4/4 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 15e0dce9151b
Successfully built 15e0dce9151b
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

Deploying to Heroku multiple times (with empty commits) I see:

```
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 697 bytes | 697.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: === Fetching app code
remote: 
remote: === Building web (Dockerfile)
remote: Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.168kB
remote: Step 1/4 : FROM ruby:2.7.2-alpine
remote: 2.7.2-alpine: Pulling from library/ruby
remote: 188c0c94c7c5: Pulling fs layer
remote: ba0772c8cbe1: Pulling fs layer
remote: dcff69af93dc: Pulling fs layer
remote: 16507e0b6111: Pulling fs layer
remote: 6aadfa8ff2a8: Pulling fs layer
remote: 16507e0b6111: Waiting
remote: 6aadfa8ff2a8: Waiting
remote: dcff69af93dc: Verifying Checksum
remote: dcff69af93dc: Download complete
remote: ba0772c8cbe1: Verifying Checksum
remote: ba0772c8cbe1: Download complete
remote: 188c0c94c7c5: Verifying Checksum
remote: 188c0c94c7c5: Download complete
remote: 6aadfa8ff2a8: Verifying Checksum
remote: 6aadfa8ff2a8: Download complete
remote: 16507e0b6111: Verifying Checksum
remote: 16507e0b6111: Download complete
remote: 188c0c94c7c5: Pull complete
remote: ba0772c8cbe1: Pull complete
remote: dcff69af93dc: Pull complete
remote: 16507e0b6111: Pull complete
remote: 6aadfa8ff2a8: Pull complete
remote: Digest: sha256:f9f332eece9188d10abb30ff6b109a1b0fee9f3e82683df8df8bf81be8121567
remote: Status: Downloaded newer image for ruby:2.7.2-alpine
remote:  ---> 79f5adf3c887
remote: Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /app
remote:  ---> Running in e8d12e411b82
remote: Removing intermediate container e8d12e411b82
remote:  ---> d5833157511c
remote: Step 3/4 : COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
remote:  ---> 47f0942ba73c
remote: Step 4/4 : RUN bundle install
remote:  ---> Running in 15b1359b8240
remote: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/....
remote: Using bundler 2.1.4
remote: Fetching ruby2_keywords 0.0.2
remote: Installing ruby2_keywords 0.0.2
remote: Fetching mustermann 1.1.1
remote: Installing mustermann 1.1.1
remote: Fetching rack 2.2.3
remote: Installing rack 2.2.3
remote: Fetching rack-protection 2.1.0
remote: Installing rack-protection 2.1.0
remote: Fetching tilt 2.0.10
remote: Installing tilt 2.0.10
remote: Fetching sinatra 2.1.0
remote: Installing sinatra 2.1.0
remote: Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 7 gems now installed.
remote: Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
remote: Removing intermediate container 15b1359b8240
remote:  ---> 318addc210bd
remote: Successfully built 318addc210bd
remote: Successfully tagged 31d653df6d02eb931fff2c0be8a4cc35b829ea54:latest
remote: 
remote: === Pushing web (Dockerfile)
remote: Tagged image "31d653df6d02eb931fff2c0be8a4cc35b829ea54" as "registry.heroku.com/secret-sierra-97497/web"
remote: The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/secret-sierra-97497/web]
remote: 0f8d2b92cc43: Preparing
remote: 1fff78e61e17: Preparing
remote: eebe8de04d9e: Preparing
remote: 410b5fd47642: Preparing
remote: 12b703c99815: Preparing
remote: e44bb72897d4: Preparing
remote: 720dc6953f4e: Preparing
remote: ace0eda3e3be: Preparing
remote: e44bb72897d4: Waiting
remote: 720dc6953f4e: Waiting
remote: ace0eda3e3be: Waiting
remote: 12b703c99815: Layer already exists
remote: 410b5fd47642: Layer already exists
remote: e44bb72897d4: Layer already exists
remote: 720dc6953f4e: Layer already exists
remote: ace0eda3e3be: Layer already exists
remote: 1fff78e61e17: Pushed
remote: eebe8de04d9e: Pushed
remote: 0f8d2b92cc43: Pushed
remote: latest: digest: sha256:11214585c68599a907c5855a213dc3d0121d9f535cb9be8ec8ed6a6ba3998913 size: 1989
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/secret-sierra-97497.git
   933054c..19603ae  master -> master
```

My heroku.yml file is:

```yaml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

Is it possible to use layer caching with Heroku docker to speed up builds?

Comment: Did you tag and publish the docker image? If yes to which registry? See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#building-and-pushing-image-s Did you specify the `docker build` command on Heroku manually or is it automatically deduced? On docker hub I'm doing: `docker build --pull --cache-from $(repo):amd64-dev -f Dockerfile.amd64 -t $(repo):amd64-dev .` followed by a `docker push $(repo):amd64-dev`.

Comment: Heroku builds the docker image as part of the deployment process.

Comment: Can you pls check that after build workspace is being cleared or what that can be one of the reason why docker cache is being invalidated.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means. What do I check for in the logs to see this?

Answer (score 5):

Heroku typically [deploys with git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-git). You push your source code. Heroku sniffs out the type of your project and selects the appropriate [build pack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks). Heroku builds a container using the build pack. The build pack knows how to do this efficiently, caching dependencies and such. Heroku then deploys that container. You need not write a Dockerfile.

Heroku supports [deploying with docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) for people who need more control over the container. These builds run in a clean environment and the behaviour you're seeing is correct. Caching old docker layers between production builds is tricky. The same command string (e.g. `apt-get install`) executed at a later time can yield different different results.

If some part of your Dockerfile is very time consuming you may find you need to wait too long to update a deployment at development time. Then you can use a [different flow](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#building-and-pushing-image-s) where you build the image locally and push it to the Heroku container registry when you want it deployed.

If you're interested in this last flow, take a look at [cloud-native build packs](https://buildpacks.io/) which allow you to build the container for your source code using the `pack` CLI.

Comment: Thanks for the response flip. To clarify - it sounds like Heroku doesn't support any layer caching when building a docker image to the best of your knowledge? The reason for my efforts is benchmarking performance issues with deploys using the traditional build packs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of using the `COPY` command, you can `ADD` the files.

This should workaround the Dockerfile caching mechanism to prevent invalidating your entire cache when you change some code.

```
FROM ruby:2.7.2-alpine
ADD Gemfile /app/
ADD Gemfile.lock  /app/
RUN bundle install
```

*PS I am not very familiar with Heroku's docker system, but ideally ADD is better than COPY and works well with caching.*

Comment: Thanks for responding, but seeing no difference between COPY and ADD. Also - per the docker guide I believe COPY is preferred unless using some extended functions offered by ADD:

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy

Comment: Perhaps this could help (I adapted my answer from here): 
https://blog.heroku.com/docker-images-with-buildpacks#a-leaky-abstraction-incrementally-writing-a-dockerfile

Comment: Also, you are right about the COPY statement.. it is preferred but not because of any performance or caching difference - https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy